# jquery / css : showing a div at the bottom of ages causes scroll bar and you can't see the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a button that shows and hides a div at the bottom of my website. When you click the button the div is revealed but it created extra scroll room and you can't see the div. Example here

http://jsfiddle.net/G2Fqe/ (if you scroll to the button and hit the blue button

The same thing happens when I place the div on top of the menu bar. Is there a way to align the viewport with the new div? Or something I don't know of? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: you want the viewport to scroll down ? or the div to open upwards ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    $(function(){

         $("div.button1-content").hide();

            $('a#button1').click(function(){
                $('div.button1-content').toggle(0, function() {
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('div.button1-content').offset().top - $('div.button1-content').height() + 'px'}, 200);  
                });
            });
   });
```

You will need to adjust this so it properly scrolls after you hide that div, but I think this is the general idea you were looking for.

Comment: I'm confused how I would do that with the toggle command any ideas?